# php class not found while in (zend-based) include_path

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-autoloader

I have a class which is in a subdirectory of my library-folder in a zend-project. So lets say my app is in /Library/WebServer/Foo/, then php's include path is:

```php
<?php echo get_include_path(); ?>
```

> /Library/WebServer/Foo/application/../library:/Library/WebServer/Foo/library:/usr/share/zend-framework/library/

So now I want to create this class, ignore the random logic, and I should be able to reach it by just saying "new MyValidator_Usernameunique()" or something like that:

> /Library/WebServer/Foo/library/MyValidator/Usernameunique.php

```php
class MyValidator_Usernameunique extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
     const USERNAME_ALREADY_EXISTS = 'usernameAlreadyUsed';
     const DATABASE_FAILED = 'userDatabaseFailure';

     protected $_messageTemplates = array(
         self::USERNAME_ALREADY_EXISTS => "De gebruikersnaam '%value%' is al in gebruik, gebruik een andere."
         self::DATABASE_FAILED => "Er ging iets mis bij het verbinden met de database."
     );

    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $magic = rand(0,3)
        if($magic==0) {
            $this->_error(self::USERNAME_ALREADY_EXISTS);
            return false;
        }
        if($magic==1) {
            $this->_error(self::DATABASE_FAILED);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

So I did exactly that:

> /Library/WebServer/Foo/library/Form/Register.php

```php
class Form_Register extends Form_FooForm 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $username = $this->createText('username', 'Gebruikersnaam')->setRequired(true);
        $username->addValidator(new MyValidator_Usernameunique());
    }
}
```

Which gives:-

> [Wed Jul 11 14:07:41 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyValidator_Usernameunique' not found in /Library/WebServer/Foo/library/Form/Register.php on line 14, referer: `http://foo/`

ignore the line number as I simplified the code a bit.

Of course, this comes natural as /Library/WebServer/Foo/library/MyValidator/ is not in my php include_path and I did not 'require' or 'include' or 'require_once' the file. Yet, as I understand, zend framework is supposed to autoload the file by replacing the _ with / and searching the include_path. And this seems to work fine for the register-form, but fails for the validator. Now, why is this? It is almost the same scenario. Moreover, it also fails when I try to create a MyValidator_Usernameunique directly in a controller-class with the same error-message.

Any thought or indication on why this happens is well appreciated. Moreover, please note, I I am not trying to fix this error, I am trying to better understand autoloading in zend. So please do not propose solutions which make the use of my validator redundant.

Comment: I'm sorry, are you looking for an answer as to why your class won't load or an explanation of auto-loading in Zend Framework? Your post is a bit unclear.

Comment: indeed it's important that also know if you autoloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, and i might missed it, but it's not really the "standard" zend layout

i kind of expect to following
in the path of your webapp (/Library/WebServer/Foo/)

- application

  - configs
  - controllers
  - etc
- library
- public

Now you want to add the validator to your library i would do it like

library

- MyApp

  - Validate

    - Validator.php

Inside Validator.php

```php
class MyApp_Validate_Validator extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Now that we have this extra part in the library we need to tell zend that we have a extra namespace with our own code in it

so in application.ini you configure it like this

```ini
autoloaderNamespaces.0 = MyApp_
```

Now the application (zend) should know where to look for your validator

so you can now do the following

create a form (best to place it in application/forms/ but it's up to you ofcourse)

```php
class Form_Register extends Zend_Form {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $username = $this->createText('username', 'Gebruikersnaam')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addValidator(new MyApp_Validate_Validator());

    }
}
```

Comment: So, what you say is that zends instead of searching all of the include_paths for the class, searches for the namespace first and then for the class? Probably tracking all the namespaces at 'boot'. Could you then indicate why it does work for Forms? I made this folder myself in the library-folder, I did not configure it in my namespace, but it does work :S By the way, I tried your suggestion, and it worked, and therefore I liked your answer. I will definitely accept it, but preferably after you could explain why this does work on forms. :) Thank you!

Comment: Zend looks in the classpath for registered namespaces.

Comment: where classpath equals include_path?

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of this answer I am going to ignore everything above 'Foo' in your path as it is irrelevant.

In order to get your validator to autoload you need to do several things.

Firstly you need to create a folder `Foo/library/My' and then add the following line to your application.ini file:-

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "My_"
```

This will tell Zend Framework where to look for your classes.

Next create the folder 'Foo/library/My/Validator' and then in that folder create 'Usernameunique.php' which should look something like this:-

```
class My_Validator_Usernameunique extends  Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    //All your class stuff goes here.
}
```

Then when you do:-

```
$username->addValidator(new My_Validator_Usernameunique());
```

It will autoload.

See the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html) for more information.

The reason that autoloading works for your form is that the 'Forms' directory is automatically added to the autoloader include path by the framework, so it knows where to find it.

Autoloading works by, as you guessed, substituting '_' for '/' and then loading the class from the resulting path. However, paths other than the default paths need to be 'registered' in application.ini as in my example. Take a look at the code in Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php to learn what actually happens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time, but I like the one below more (sorry). To be honest, sentences like "This will tell Zend Framework where to look for your classes." add to the confusion, as they do not explain at all what a namespace is and why it is necessary. I could say exactly the same for a folder I have put in my php's include_path, so is a namespace equivalent to an include_path? Don't think so. Also "see the manual" is a bit odd when you afterwards seem to ignore my question why this does work for Form, and does not for MyValidator. I didn't find a thing on that in the manual.

Comment: @Herbert I've added a small sentence in response to your comment. To be fair, I did ask you for clarification in a comment to your question, but you did not reply.

Comment: yougave me about 15 minutes to clarify before just repeating from the zend-framework-documentation in your answer. However you did clarify that I need to register namespaces, which I did not know before. Up to date I am still not clear on why it works for forms but not for validators :S I think I will have to live with that :) Anyway, thank you for the effort.